# Customizing Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Free) Tool sidebar

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

Is it possible to customizing the side bar on the right Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Free)?  If so, how?

The available documentation [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/workspace-basics.html) shows options that don't appear when I try to duplicate them (e.g. under Add or remove shortcuts of tools in the right pane, "Remove Shortcut" is not displayed when I right click).

I specifically want to add Certificate to the tool bar so its always visible
I would, if possible, also like to remove the other unused / unusable tools.

Thanks
Ed

[image: screenshot of sidebar]

Comment: Yes. I'm not at a computer right now, but I did this a few weeks ago and will look at a computer tomorrow to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same: Add the Certificate tool to the right hand Tools section. The only info I have found about [customizing the Tools section](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/AcroApps.html#Right-handToolsPaneCustomization(DC)), is about Adobe Acrobat (Paid version). I haven't  found a way of doing that in Reader (Free version), but I did find a way to hide the unusable tools like *Export PDF*, *Edit PDF*, etc.

### Registry info for every tool

In the following registry key, there are sub-keys (like c0, c1, and so on) containing the descriptions of every Tool.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AcroApp\cRegistered
```

The string value in ***tTitle*** contains the title of the Tool as it appears on the right hand side.

The string value in ***tPath*** contains the corresponding .aapp file that can be found inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroApp\ENU`

### How to hide Tools

To hide the tools I didn't need, I used the above registry info to find the file names of the .aapp files corresponding to the Tools I didn't need (for example, the file name of the *Export PDF* Tool is *EPDF_Full.aapp*). Then I renamed each .aapp file I didn't need to .aapp.bak in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroApp\ENU`

The next time I opened Reader again, the tools I had renamed disappeared after a short while :)